# How to create custom header in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, header, local.xml

I want to create the custom header in Magento 1.9. I attached the screenshot of the header like this

[image]

I  have tried the following code.
 I have created the static block and static block calling in the header.phtml file

```
     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('custom_block_id')->toHtml() ?>
```

but this code is not working .please suggest me

I have added this original header not working. Menu and logo not displaying.

```
     <!--- custom header---->    
  <reference name="header">
      <block type="page/header" name="header">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/customheader.phtml</template></action> 
     </block>    
 </reference> 
        <!--- original header---->
         <reference name="header">
        <!-- Search box wrapper -->
        <block type="page/html_header" name="search_wrapper" template="page/html/search_wrapper.phtml">
            <action method="insert">
                <block>top.search</block>
            </action>
        </block>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the code bellow in : `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/layout/local.xml`

   ```
   <reference name="header">
       <block type="{block}/{type}" name="custom.header" template="page/html/custom-header.phtml" before="-"/>
   </reference>
   ```
2. Create your custom header in : `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/page/html/custom-header.phtml`
3. Add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom.header'); ?>` in `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/page/html/header.phtml`

   **Info** : in `<block type="{block}/{type}"` if you haven't a custom block for your phtml, please put : `<block type="core/template" ...`

   `before="-"` to place it at the **top** of the header container.

**Update:**

For a **Static block**:

in `local.xml`

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="cms/block" name="custom.header">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block-id-here</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Then : `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/page/html/header.phtml`

Add this : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom.header'); ?>`

Comment: @pirnce i  have created static block then how can write ?

Comment: Please Look my update

Comment: Hi prince  i have updated local.xml and custom-header.phtml in above theme folder but it's not working

Comment: Clean the cache, and check well the id of your custom block `<block_id>block-id-here</block_id>` `block-id-here` you replace it by the id of your static block

Comment: first i have created custom-header.phtml and In that phtml file added div content and  that phtml file called in local.xml file using <block type="core/template"

Comment: But you told me that you dont need a phtml but a static block, So you need a phtml or static block or a static block in that phtml ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81274/discussion-between-pramod24-and-prince).

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this code in your xml :

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="customheader" template="customheader.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

And write your custom code in **customheader.phtml** file.

It may be helpful for you.

Comment: i have added custom header but original header content not working. my menu and logo not display.